# Download an HTML page and check content

Tags: perl, http, command-line, wget

This is my perl script:

```
#!/usr/local/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP 5.64;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $browser=LWP::UserAgent->new;

$browser->agent('Mozilla/5.0'); #etc

my $cookie_jar=HTTP::Cookies->new(
        file => '/home/andrew/Documents/Perl/CheckResultsURL/cookies.txt',
            autosave => 1,
);

$browser->$cookie_jar($cookie_jar);

my $url="http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=john";

#send request
my $response=$browser->get($url);

if($response->content=~/about(\s)((\d)+)/){
        print "yes";
}

print $response->content;
```

I get this error:

```
Can't locate object method "Cookies=HASH(0x22bf388)" via package "HTTP" at lwp.pl line 17.
```

And sadly I don't know  what to do. Probably it has to do with a cookie control I don't pass. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the line `$browser->$cookie_jar($cookie_jar);`

should probably be `$browser->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);` (note removal of extra '$')